# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'albersUsa' of undefined

Tags: d3.js

This may have been asked before but I'm hoping I can get an answer specific to the issue I'm encountering. I'm new to d3 and I'm trying to plot one lat/long for now (I'll do the rest when I'm successful with the first one). Appreciate any help from the experts. Thanks.

Trying to plot a cell site in a specific area.

Here's the code:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="datamaps.usa.min.js"></script>

<style>
  #map {
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
 }
</style>

</head>

<body>
 <div id="map"></div>
 <script>
    var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.7830600, -96.8066700),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  styles: [{
    "stylers": [{
      "saturation": -75
    }, {
      "lightness": 10
    }]
  }]
});


var places = [
  {
   name: "Site1",
   location: {
   latitude: 32.7935,
   longitude: -97.9619
   }
 }
]

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa();


// add circles to svg
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(places)
    .enter().append("circle", "circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + projection([
        d.location.longitude, d.location.latitude ]) + ")";
  });



  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using?

Comment: Here's what shown in d3.min.js -  https://d3js.org Version 4.7.3. Copyright 2017 Mike Bostock.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

D3 v4 featured "[the great namespace flattening](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#hierarchies-d3-hierarchy)", changing the namespace of D3v3. Instead of d3.geo.projection you use d3.geoProjection:

`d3.geo.albersUsa` → `d3.geoAlbersUsa`

`d3.geo.albers` → `d3.geoAlbers`

The same applies to all methods of d3.geo, such as `d3.geo.path`:

`d3.geo.path` → `d3.geoPath`

And so forth for other `d3.geo` methods.

`d3.geo` is no longer an object as of d3v4, so `d3.geo` will be undefined in v4, and its property `.albersUsa` will not be found and an error generated.

I am not sure if datamaps has been upgraded for d3v4 compatibility or what conflicts might arise from any incompatibility. It may be that it is easier to downgrade to d3v3.

Comment: @AndrewReid, thanks. It did worked. Also had the same issue with d3.geo.path and just wrote it as d3.geoPath